# Eigen vectors and injectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a linear operator defined on $D(A) \subset \mathbb{C}^{\infty}=\lbrace \left( x_1,x_2, \dots \right) : x_i \in \mathbb{C} \rbrace$. Consider $$B=\prod_{k=1}^n \left( A-\lambda_kI \right) , $$ where $\lambda_k \in \mathbb{C}$ and $I$ is identity. Assume that B is not injective in $D(B) \subset \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. Also, for $0 \neq x  \in D(B) \cap \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ we have $$\forall_{k=1, \dots , n} \quad \left( A- \lambda_kI \right)x \neq 0 $$ Is $B$ injective in $D(B) \cap \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ ?

Comment: I don't think it's a contrapositive. This concerns injectivity on a limited domain. This would be a corollary of the previous question but not the other way around. This is a full version of a problem. I need this lemma to finish another theorem, which I am not going to post here, because it's too long and it doesn't change anything.